# how to implement HTC's FieldTest app?

Tags: android

I want read low level information from the modem.
There is a simple way that's mentioned in google groupe: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/tVyNMnXtcEI
the app is in this link(http://phoneftd.blogspot.com/2009/03/google-g1-phone-field-test.html
) but I couldn't find away to implement it.
could you help me?